# rows.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, sql, discord.js

I want to create a leaderboard for my discord users.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const sql = require("sqlite")

sql.open("../score.sqlite")

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {  
    sql.get("SELECT * FROM scores GROUP BY userId ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10")
        .then(rows => {
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setFooter('Bot')
                .setTimestamp()
            let userArray = []
            let moneyArray = []

            rows.forEach(row => {
                userArray.push(row.userId)
                moneyArray.push(row.points)
            })

            embed.addField('Name', userArray.join('\n'), true)
            embed.addField('Money', moneyArray.join('\n'), true)
            message.channel.send({embed})
        })
}
```

I don't understand why forEach is no function.

Comment: What type of value does the `sql.get` Promise return? If it's not an Array it may not have the forEach function as a property.

Comment: So you get error message at `rows.forEach(row=>{` that says "forEach is no function"?

Comment: yes exactly @codtex

Comment: Well if `rows` is not an array that's why the error happens as stated from @MatthewLewis. Maybe could you show us the structure of `rows` object or try using `for(let prop in rows)` to loop your data or `Object.values(rows).forEach(....`

Comment: @Monkeyyy11 can you provide us the instance of rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the sqlite library you're using is [this Promise-adding wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite), [the documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback) states of the value returned from `sql.get` that:

> If the result set is empty, [it] is `undefined`, otherwise it is an object containing the values for the first row. The property names correspond to the column names of the result set.

As your `rows` parameter is an Object, is doesn't have the forEach function on it. It also will be an Object containing values for a single row—if you want to get the entire set of rows from the database, you should use `sql.all` not `sql.get`.

Here's what using `Object.keys` would look like:

```
Object.keys(rows).forEach(key => {
    userArray.push(rows[key].userId);
    moneyArray.push(rows[key].points);
});
```